# JPA - MAX of COUNT or SELECT FROM SELECT

Tags: select, jpa, count, subquery, max

I wrote the following query for MySQL:

```
SELECT subquery.t1_column1, 
    subquery.t2_id, 
    MAX(subquery.val)
FROM (
    SELECT t1.column1 as t1_column1, 
        t1.id_t2 AS t2_id,
        count(1) AS val
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id_t2
    GROUP BY t1.id_t2
) subquery
GROUP BY t1_column1
```

And I'd like to translate it into JPA (JPQL or criteria query).

I don't know how to make this max(count) thing, and JPA doesn't seem to like the SELECT FROM SELECT...

If anyone has an idea other than native queries (I'll do it for now), it would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't checked tha JPA specification, but given that the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-subqueries) says

> Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where
>   clauses.

I very much doubt that your query can be transformed in a valid JPQL query.

You'll have to keep using this native SQL query.

Comment: It is not a valid JPQL query at all, it's native SQL.My goal is to translate it into JPQL avoiding native queries if it's possible.
If it's not I can live with that, just wanted to know.

Comment: Ah, OK. So my answer is: you're not going to be able to translate it to JPQL.

Answer (score 5):

JPA 2.0 JPQL does not support sub-selects in the from clause.  You may want to try to rewrite your query, or use a native SQL query.

EclipseLink 2.4 will support sub-selects in the FROM clause,

see,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Sub-selects_in_FROM_clause