# How to count all groups returned by a group by query in JPQL?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

If I have a group by query

```
Select e.field1, e.field2...
from Entity w
group by e.field1, e.field2...
```

How can I count the number of rows not using NativeQuery?
I need to do something like this:

```
select count(*) from
(Select e.field1, e.field2...
from Entity w
group by e.field1, e.field2...)
```

Is there any way to do with JPQL?

Comment: Your question does not really makes sense as of now. The code you put in the question does what you describe what you want. But clearly, you want to do something else. Please elaborate.

Comment: No, because I can't use "count(*)" in JPQL. I need a different way to indicate the same but in JPQL syntax.

Comment: So, after rereading a few times. Don't you need multiple `group by` queries and getting the `count(*)` for all of them?

Comment: What do you mean you can't use `*`? Why?

Comment: I believe that JPQL can not support asterisk (*) in COUNT function.

Comment: That's definitely false.

Comment: Ok, but what are not supported for sure are subselects in "from" clauses as James said (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10705205/2098871)... I'm afraid I'll have to accept the same answer... because that query is not working at all.

Comment: Well that's true, but that does not mean that your requeriments can't be done in JPQL.

Answer (score 0):

Derived tables are not supported in JPQL, so, the best way to do it is to run a native SQL query.

After all, [there is a very good reason why both JPA and Hibernate offer support for SQL queries](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-jpa-entitymanager-createnativequery-is-a-magic-wand/), don't you agree?

Comment: I totally agree. I updated my answer. The solution is very simple, it's called SQL.

Answer (score 0):

in oracle you can this hql

```
Select sum(count(*) - count(*) + 1)
from Entity e
group by e.field1, e.field2...
```

but dose not work in postgres